# How to link a webservice in AJAX update panel in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

How can I link a Web Service in my update panel?

I was asked this question in an interview. I have searched it on Google and also in books.
Can anyone explain it? Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.
Refer this link to know more in details about **Understanding ASP.NET AJAX Web Services**

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-web-services

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398898%28v=vs.100%29.aspx